# "always" keyword in apache header when setting CORS capabilities

Tags: ajax, apache, cors

So I was setting CORS on my server, following the [enable-cors.org](http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html) website. I ended up with this configuration (on apache 2.4) :

```
#Allowing CORS capabilities
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www|othersubdomain\.)?(mywebsite.com)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0$1

    Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE"
</IfModule>
# ...
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # needed for CORS
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
</IfModule>
```

It works now, but I would like to know **why I need to put the `always` keyword ?**

Otherwise, those headers are never sent to the client (from another domain name), on an ajax request (which is, well, the whole purpose of this system).

Comment: The documentation [lists some reasons you might need to use always](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html#header) but we don't know enough about how your system works to tell which ones are applicable to your case.

Comment: I honestly didn't understand a single word from this part of the documentation :)
I know my way around apache configuration, not its internal.
What would you want to know about the system ?